# Creating a metric for True Positives with make_scorer

Tags: python, decision-tree, metrics

I'm trying to create a metric to optimize the precision of True Positives of the positive class in a Decision Tree classifier:

```
metrica = make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label=1, greater_is_better=True, 
                      average="binary")
```

And then using `RandomizedSearchCV` for hyperparameters tune:

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, scoring= metrica, 
                                   param_distributions=param_dist, 
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search)
```

I get the following result:

[image: RandomSearchCV results]

Tunning the Tree with these parameters, I get zero percent of True Positives ...

[image: Zero percent]

Simply changing `splitter='random'` to `'best'`, I get better at 82% accuracy in the positive class.

What is failing in my metric or `RandomSearchCV`?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your `RandomizedSearchCV` or your scorer, though you could have just used `precision_score` as the scorer instead of using `make_scorer`, because by default, the `precision_score` has the parameters that you've set it as:

The point of grid searching (or randomized search) is to find the best hyperparameter values for the model that you're using. In this case, you chose to use a classic decision tree. Keep in mind, that this model is pretty basic. You're essentially building one tree so the important hyperparameters are the ones that affect the tree depth and the criteria for splitting.

You mention that when the `splitter` strategy was changed to "best", you got a better accuracy score. Well, `splitter` also happens to be a hyperparameter of the model, so it could be fed as an additional parameter in the grid search space.

Another potential reason why you might have gotten the low precision score after running the randomized search is that you might not have given it enough iterations to find the right hyperparameter combinations.

Ultimately, here would be my pointers:

1. Decision tree is a very basic model. It's prone to overfitting. I would recommend an ensemble model instead such as a random forest, which consists of multiple decision trees.
2. Consider what hyperparameters you want to tune and how exhaustively you want to search within that hyperparameter space to get the best model. You should start with a couple of hyperparameters to search on, starting with the important ones like `max_depth` or `min_samples_split` and then scaling up. This will be experimental on your side. There's no right or wrong here, but keep track of the best parameters found.
3. You should consider how well balanced your classes are. Models tend to be pretty biased if there's too much of one class over another. If there is a class imbalance, you can control for the imbalance using the `class_weight` argument.